# Getting files from directory and filtering them

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filtering, fs

I'm trying to get all files from a directory, filtered them and display the result as an array..
I've tried a bunch of stuff but none seem to work as i need them to so ill ask here, below is my code.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/fonts')

files.forEach(el => {
   el.includes('.json') ? files[files.indexOf(el)].replace('.json', '') : files.splice(files[files.indexOf(el)], 1)
});

console.log(files)
```

I tried promises but I am inexperienced with them so I'm asking here. If you could help it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter, map, and slice functions:

```js
const files = ["fileone.json", "filetwo.json", "filethree, filefour.md"]
filteredFiles = files.filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith(".json"))
    .map(fileName => fileName.slice(0, -5))
console.log(filteredFiles)
```

`filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function

`map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array

`slice()` method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object (we've selected the characters in positions 0 through [final-5] in our example)

<sub>Edit: answer now using `endsWith` instead of `includes`, as suggested in comments</sub>

Comment: found that if i use `.endsWith(".json")` could be better just in case any other files include it in their name, still your is great!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript filter function:

```js
var myfiles = ["file1.json", "file2.txt", "file3.jpeg"]
myfiles = myfiles.filter(o=> o.indexOf(".json") !== -1)
console.log(myfiles)
```